# Child Rotation in Unity3D

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

I was trying Unity3d when I had a strange problem:

I created an empty object A and its child object cube B.

Properties of A:
Position-(0,0,0)
Rotation-(0,0,0)
Scale-(1,1,1)

Properties of B:
Position-(0,2,0)
Rotation-(0,0,0)
Scale-(1,4,1)

I have made a C# script having a Transform object. It rotates using transform.localrotation only along z-axis.
The problem is that if in Unity Editor I attach A as transform, B seems to rotate along one of its corners (I don't know how was that corner chosen) and if I attach B, it seems to rotate along its centre.
I don't understand why this is happening? I know that in localrotation, parent rotation is taken into account. But initial rotation of A and B are both zero, so it should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify `transform.localRotation` directly, you are modifying a quaternion.

Usualy you should not modify quaternions directly:

> Tthey (sic!) are based on complex numbers and are not easy to understand intuitively. You almost never access or modify individual Quaternion components (x,y,z,w); most often you would just take existing rotations (e.g. from the Transform) and use them to construct new rotations (e.g. to smoothly interpolate between two rotations).

*taken from the unity3d doc: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html*

**Try using `transform.Rotate()` or `transform.localEulerAngles`. That should fix your problem.**

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html 
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: transform.rotate will give me absolute rotation. I need to rotate B relative to its current rotation.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. Did you try `transform.localEulerAngles`?